# Should I trust the Garbage Collector after calling Bitmap.recycle()?

Tags: android, memory, memory-leaks, bitmap, garbage-collection

I have some code which is loading an image into an OpenGL texture.  In the process, I end up loading 3 bitmaps, since I need to load the original bitmap (sized appropriately for the display) and reorient the bitmap based on EXIF data.  I'm very quickly calling `.recycle()` on each bitmap, but I'm noticing that my memory doesn't seem to change.

Here's what the Memory Monitor shows:

[image: memory monitor]

As you can see, after loading the image I'm using about 60MB of memory.  When I rotate the device that drops off a bit then comes back up.  That leads me to think there is no leak, since the memory never goes above that.

When I click the GC button in the memory analyzer, my memory footprint drops dramatically to around 8 MB.  This makes sense as the three bitmaps created during the process were recycled, so can be garbage collected.  Then you can see that when I rotate again and the activity is rebuilt, the memory jumps right back up.

Here's my code to show you why so many bitmaps are created and when they're recycled.

```
void layoutImage() {
    ...    
    Bitmap bitmap = loadOrientedConstrainedBitmapWithBackouts(...);
    imageTexture = new GLTexture(bitmap);
    bitmap.recycle(); // recycle bitmap 2
}

Bitmap loadOrientedConstrainedBitmapWithBackouts(Context context, Uri uri, int maxSize) {
    ...
    Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapWithBackouts(context, uri, sampleSize); // create bitmap 1
    ...
    Bitmap out = orientBitmap(bitmap, orientation); // create bitmap 2
    bitmap.recycle(); // recycle bitmap 1
    return out;
}

Bitmap orientBitmap(Bitmap source, int orientation) {
    ...
    return Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight, matrix, true);  // create bitmap 3
}
```

I'm not really sure that this is a problem, so to speak, since the memory isn't climbing (so no leak), but I'm curious when it stays so high.  Since forcing a garbage collection clears it just fine, should I assume that if the system needs that memory it will be collected on the next GC pass?  It's been running the whole time I've been writing this and is still sitting comfortably at 60 MB.

**Question 1**: Can I just trust that the garbage collector will take that memory back if needed?

Also, if we're supposed to be so judiciously recycling our bitmaps, why do so many of the Bitmap methods say things like "The new bitmap may be the same object as source, or a copy may have been made."  Do I really have to check the equality every time I use those methods to recycle the bitmap if it's a different object?

**Question 2**: When using Bitmap creation methods, that may or may not return the same bitmap or a copy, do I need to check source and output equality to recycle the source if it's a copy?

## Edit:

I have tried analyzing this with MAT, using a heap dump at peak usage (should be 60 MB), but it only reports 18.2 MB of usage and nothing unusual looking.  Could they be reading things differently?

[image]

Comment: "That leads me to think there is no leak" -- I would recommend that you use MAT, rather than guessing. "if we're supposed to be so judiciously recycling our bitmaps" -- on modern versions of Android, you are supposed to be *reusing* your bitmaps, via `inBitmap` on `BitmapFactory.Options`. `recycle()` is a bit of a hack, primarily for Android 1.x/2.x, to help the GC along a bit. Quoting the current `Bitmap` source, "This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more references to this bitmap".

Comment: Now, in your case, you may have no need to reuse the bitmaps, which is fine. If MAT indicates that your bitmaps are not being strongly held, they will eventually be GC'd. How quickly that happens will depend upon a variety of factors, but if nothing else a `GC_FOR_ALLOC` will occur if an attempt to allocate something fails, and that's going to collect all possible garbage.

Comment: Re: reusing bitmaps, I am using the bitmap static factory methods that take a source bitmap, I wonder how that compares to inBitmap in the Options.  I also have no reason to keep the bitmaps around since I'm just using them to pass to OpenGL, then they're gone until I have to reinitialize the view (via rotation, etc.).

Comment: How much of the MAT heap was Bitmap memory? If you ran that trace on a 2.x device, the bitmap memory won't show up under a MAT heap. Otherwise, the discrepancy may just be between MM reporting heap size information and MAT reporting the size of actual objects.

Comment: @Devunwired The biggest consumer (that 4.4 MB) is actually `com.android.content.res.Resources`.  Then we get into `java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod`.  This all makes sense given the views I have showing on screen (ImageViews from resources).  The allocation reported in MAT is more of what I would expect, it's curious that the MM is showing so much more, when it clearly gets successfully collected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1: Can I just trust that the garbage collector will take that memory back if needed?

Yes. If the incoming references are cleared, the garbage collector will take the memory when it is needed (typically for a new allocation). Calling `recycle()` doesn't help this process along or make it happen any faster.

The `recycle()` method exists because `Bitmap` objects were not counted against the heap until Android 3.0; so the method was helpful to assist the GC since it didn't otherwise have a record of that memory counted against its heap. In 3.0+, the memory is tracked against the heap so this extra bookkeeping isn't necessary anymore.

> Question 2: When using Bitmap creation methods, that may or may not return the same bitmap or a copy, do I need to check source and output equality to recycle the source if it's a copy?

The `createBitmap()` method will return the same object if:

- The source is immutable
- `x` and `y` are both zero
- `width` and `height` match the source width and height
- No transformation matrices have been applied

Since it looks like you are passing in a transformation matrix, you will always get a copy unless the matrix is identity for some reason. But again, no real need to `recycle()` unless you are still supporting 2.x versions.